# Add column into Javascript function in .js file

Tags: javascript

I have to add a line of code into existing js function. But I cannot add it right into, because it can interfere into future updates of this .js file. I have to add it from another .js file.

Part of code I want add line into is:

```
(function($) {

if (typeof _wpcf7 == 'undefined' || _wpcf7 === null) {
    _wpcf7 = {};
}

_wpcf7 = $.extend({
    cached: 0
}, _wpcf7);

$.fn.wpcf7InitForm = function() {
    this.ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options) {
            $form.wpcf7ClearResponseOutput();
            $form.find('[aria-invalid]').attr('aria-invalid', 'false');
            $form.find('img.ajax-loader').css({ visibility: 'visible' });
        },
```

And the line I want to add is:

```
$form.find('input.wpcf7-submit').val('Sending');
```

The part I want add should be right under:

```
$form.find('img.ajax-loader').css({ visibility: 'visible' });
```

How can I achive it?

Sorry for my poor language, and thanks in advance for answers :)

Comment: You can't do it without touching the original js file. Why exactly can you not change the file?

Comment: File is part of outside program, and in future can be updated. And if i understand correctly, if i would just add part of code right into function, when updated my part would dissapear.

Comment: You mean it's in a file not hosted by you? From a CDN? If that's so, you should just host it yourself and make changes.

Comment: No, its a part of wordpress widget. All files are hosted by me.

Comment: Then there is no problem changing it yourself so long as you don't update it.